# Gamma spectroscopy - Nuclide identification

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

I have a question about what the usual practice is for nuclide identification in gamma spectroscopy.

For example, if I see a line at 477 keV, I would write that the origin of this line is $^7Be$. As I understand it, that gamma actually comes from the relaxation of the 477 keV excited state of $^7Li$, but that state is populated by the EC-decay of $^7Be$, so convention is to write that the origin is $^7Be$ (the "parent"). This makes sense to me.

My problem comes when I'm putting identifications in which are gammas produced by neutron capture.

As an example, I see a line at 352 keV. This is an energy level of $^{57}Fe$. This energy level is populated by neutron capture on $^{56}Fe$. Intuitively, in a similar way to the case of $^7Be$ above, I want to write down that the origin is $^{56}Fe$. However, convention in the case of neutron capture seems to be that I should write that the origin is actually $^{57}Fe$.

Basically I want to clarify what the convention is when it comes to identifying the origin of various gamma emissions, be they neutron induced or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the origin of either convention, so I am reluctant to make any absolute statements, but as an experimenter the question I ask myself is *"What material have I learned is present in the sample?"* or perhaps *"What material do I bring into the lab to observe this line?"*.

The answer to these questions would be Berylium-7 in the former case and Iron-56 in the latter.

No idea if that is historically accurate, but it could give you a framework for understanding which convention is at work.

Answer (score -1):

Iron-57 is a stable isotope , so it does not emit any gamma ray .
You measure a prompt gamma from a nuclear reaction ( n , gamma )  .

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it's not an answer to the question.